# Javascript doesn't refresh in Django loop

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a Django template (html), and a javascript in it that I want to loop for various pair values. It doesn't loop.

Here is the code in the template rsmgui.html:

```
{% for field in elements %}

            <input type="hidden" id="theFieldLabelID" name="theFieldLabel" value="{{ field.label }}">
            <input type="hidden" id="theFieldID" name="theField" value="{{ field }}">

            <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/loadStorage.js"></script>
{% endfor %}
```

The javascript loadStorage.js looks like this:

```
var myFieldLabel=document.getElementById("theFieldLabelID").value.replace(/ /g,"")

var myField = document.getElementById("theFieldID")
alert("Label = " + myFieldLabel);
localStorage.setItem(myFieldLabel, JSON.stringify(myField));
```

But it doesn't loop, it gets the first pair and then repeats it for the number of pairs. Any ideas how to "flush" the javascript so it reloads each time?

Comment: You're placing the `<script>` element with the same source each loop. There's really no point in doing this. Why do you want to reload the script? It seems that doing so would not do anything useful, even if it worked. Perhaps what you want to do is have the JS as an inline script that is a template file you can include in each loop with new values EG `{% include 'myapp/js/loadStorage.snippet' with somevar=field %}`

Comment: Hello - The purpose of wanting to rerun the script is to load each pair from the elements tuple into localStorage. In my test data, I have 5 key-value pairs. But it never resets the key-values, it just duplicates the first set 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

> it gets the first pair and then repeats it for the number of pairs

That is because [getElementById only returns first element](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp). Element ID should be unique across the page. Without changing your logic, there are two solutions below.

First one is to add [loop counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for) suffix:

```html
{% for field in elements %}

            <input type="hidden" id="theFieldLabel{{ forloop.counter }}" name="theFieldLabel" value="{{ field.label }}">
            <input type="hidden" id="theField{{ forloop.counter }}" name="theField" value="{{ field }}">

            <script>var id_suffix = "{{ forloop.counter }}"</script>
            <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/loadStorage.js"></script>
{% endfor %}
```

```js
var myFieldLabel=document.getElementById("theFieldLabel" + id_suffix).value.replace(/ /g,"")

var myField = document.getElementById("theField" + id_suffix)
alert("Label = " + myFieldLabel);
localStorage.setItem(myFieldLabel, JSON.stringify(myField));
```

Second one is to use getElementsByName:

```html
{% for field in elements %}

            <input type="hidden" id="theFieldLabelID" name="theFieldLabel" value="{{ field.label }}">
            <input type="hidden" id="theFieldID" name="theField" value="{{ field }}">

            <script>var index = {{ forloop.counter0 }}</script>
            <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/loadStorage.js"></script>
{% endfor %}
```

```js
var myFieldLabel=document.getElementsByName("theFieldLabel")[index].value.replace(/ /g,"")

var myField = document.getElementsByName("theField")[index]
alert("Label = " + myFieldLabel);
localStorage.setItem(myFieldLabel, JSON.stringify(myField));
```

Considering @sytech comment, you can wrap your code into function with a parameter is the index/id_suffix. Then call it with necessary value.

```html
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/loadStorage.js"></script>
{% for field in elements %}

            <input type="hidden" id="theFieldLabel{{ forloop.counter }}" name="theFieldLabel" value="{{ field.label }}">
            <input type="hidden" id="theField{{ forloop.counter }}" name="theField" value="{{ field }}">

            <script>loadStorage("{{ forloop.counter }}");</script>
{% endfor %}
```

```js
function loadStorage(id_suffix)
{
    var myFieldLabel=document.getElementById("theFieldLabel" + id_suffix).value.replace(/ /g,"")

    var myField = document.getElementById("theField" + id_suffix)
    alert("Label = " + myFieldLabel);
    localStorage.setItem(myFieldLabel, JSON.stringify(myField));
}
```

Comment: Hai Lang, THANK YOU! It works beautifully using the first suggestion you provided.